# form HTML not send after click

Tags: html, forms

Im use form html my probleme after click submit send nothing in my brother

```
<form method="get" id="booking-form" role="form" action="">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
     <i class="fa fa-map-marker rechercheIndex"></i>
     <label class="sr-only" >Recherche</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ville">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" >
  </div>
</form>
```

After click button send nothing

Im expetected return value in my form

I found solution. Just add name in my input name="city"

```
<label for="city">Enter city: </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ville" name="ville">
```

Comment: Submit must be sending the form details to some handler. Where are you expecting the inputs from your form to be handled? To be more specific, which script/service would take the input from your form and process it?

Comment: Please vote up my answer

Answer (score 1):

set Action Attribute to specific Action Page
you should must PHP or other server side language to interact with forms

**Index.php**

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Welcome.php**

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

In first line  ,we need to give path were form get collect

Ex :-

In this the form get collect in "/action_page.php"

Comment: Thank for your answer but you solution don't work for me